# Can't login into MySQL when installing MediaWiki (HY000/1045)

Tags: server, mysql, mediawiki

Trying to bind MediaWiki to mysql-server while installing it (the second step of installation) but got an error message:

```
Cannot access the database: :real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES). Check the host, username and password and try again. If using "localhost" as the database host, try using "127.0.0.1" instead (or vice versa).
```

It is Ubuntu 18.04, mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.30, MediaWiki 1.34.1,

wiki is at /var/www/html

I am successfully login in mysql just at terminal but in installation process.

Comment: Have you set a root password for mysql?

Comment: Yes, I am logging in mysql itself with no issues. And with the same credentials got en error while installation via browser.

Comment: 18.04 uses socket authentication by default, so logging in does not mean that you have set a password...

Answer (score 1):

By default, MariaDB uses socket authentication for 18.04.

This works when you can run the process connecting to your MySQL/MariaDB-server as the same user as in MariaDB. However, for good reasons, the web server does not run as root.

The work around is to either set a root password for MySQL/MariaDB, or create a mediawiki user and database in MySQL/MariaDB manually.

To create a user and database manually, start a mysql shell with `sudo mysql`, and run the following SQL queries:

```
CREATE DATABASE wikidb;
CREATE USER 'wikiuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wikidb.* TO 'wikiuser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Change `wikidb` to your desired database name, `wikiuser` to your desired username, and `password` to your desired password. Note that password should be long and complex; you will never have to enter this manually anyway.

Further details are [available in the installation manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:Installing_MediaWiki#MariaDB/MySQL) of MW.

Comment: issue still persist.

Comment: Posting your password publicly is not a good idea. However, the output indicates that it's OK. Use the newly created db name, username and password in mediawiki to connect to MariaDB.

Comment: Do you mean shift from mysql to mariadb, because the credentials I made appear the same error in installation script

Comment: MariaDB and mysql is essentially the same for now. MariaDB is afaik the default for 18.04. I would suggest you pop by [chat] - it's easier to clarify issues there than in comments...